# Reading variable width tokens from scanner in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Given an expression such as:

```
4*x+16-455
```

I need to be able to retrieve tokens individually. Thus, I need:

```
4
*
x
+
16
-
455
```

I can't just use "nextInt()" as it's all one string - how can I get around this? I thought about splitting by the operators, and then alternating between the two which should work but it seems like there should be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Take a look at the [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Comment: That's great - I've looked at that. My question is - how do I define a token?

Comment: It looks StringTokenizer can do what I want, actually..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to read the whole string and split it to the tokens. You can select token by regexp. Your example can be parsed to tokens by the following regexp:

```
String s = "4*x+16-455";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+|[a-z]+|[*//+//-])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

The output:

```
4
*
x
+
16
-
455
```

If you need more clever splitter with lot of different tokens, consider modifying regexp or better use Interpreter pattern to make your solution more readable.